# What statistical test should I do?

Tags: r

I want to test if there is a particular tree size preference for nest densities (if there are more nest occurrences on trees with larger/smaller tree sizes). What statistical test would be most suitable? (chi-squared goodness of fit or chi-squared independence/association, regression, ANOVA, Kruskal Wallis, correlation).

I have one column of data for tree sizes in centimetres and one column for nest densities (count data). And for the test, how should I set out my data so that it will give me accurate estimates? Should i use ranges like 40-50cm, 50-60cm for my independent variable or should i list out the individual sizes from data collection?

Comment: Do you have data and need to know how to analyze? Or are you planning a study and need help with the design? Either way please give more detail.

Comment: correlation test should work out, since its measures 2 numerical relationship (is it likely to be linear relationship or reversed relationship) which is tree size and nest densities, but it depends to your dataset, what would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You have only 2 variables. The first thing to do is to plot the data. This will give you a good idea of what the association  is. In particular, if it seems to be plausibly linear, then you can do a basic linear regression, or just compute the Pearson correlation coefficient. If the association is nonlinear then you could transform one or both variables first, to obtain a linear association, or with a regression model, introduce non linear terms.

Do not put the data into ranges. This just loses information.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so then please consider marking it as a the accepted answer and (if you haven't already) upvoting it. If not, please could you let us know why so that it can be improved